# Verb order with multiple secondary sentences

Tags: verb, word-order

Is this sentence correct in terms of verb order? And if not what would be correct and why?

> Ich wusste nicht, dass wir die Möglichkeit haben, ein Artefakt mit anderen Kollegen mitzubenutzen, die nicht in der Gruppe sind.

I have the feeling that one of these “secondary” sentences can be put together with multiple verbs at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We Germans like verbs at the end.

> Ich wusste nicht, dass wir die Möglichkeit haben, ein Artefakt mit anderen Kollegen, die nicht in der Gruppe sind, mitzubenutzen.

It makes it clearer that *nicht in der Gruppe* refers to *Kollegen* and not *Artefakt.*

Answer (score 3):

Inserting verbs (and some other stuff) between a subject and a subclause or infinitive constructions relating to it is fine in general, as many sentences only become understandable this way. Without this, your example would read:

> Ich wusste nicht, dass wir die Möglichkeit, ein Artefakt mit anderen Kollegen, die nicht in der Gruppe sind, mitzubenutzen, haben.

You should not insert a subject though (or something else to which the subclause or infinitive construction may also refer), e.g.:

> Ich wusste nicht, dass wir die Möglichkeit haben, mit anderen Kollegen ein Artefakt mitzubenutzen, die nicht in der Gruppe sind.

Here, the relative clause *(die nicht in der Gruppe sind)* is very difficult to relate to *Kollegen,* though grammatical gender and number make it non-ambiguous in theory.