# Position of relative clause

Tags: word-order

I have this part of a sentence:

> ... deswegen hatte ich ein paar Worte geschrieben, über was ich machen kann.

That syntax makes more sense, or that:

> ... deswegen hatte ich ein paar Worte, über was ich machen kann, geschrieben.

and would it be any real difference in spoken German, compared to written?

Comment: The participle of "schreiben" is "geschrieben". As this is not an essential part of your question, I just fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it was an important mistake :)

Comment: Furthermore, I think your question is just about the position of the subclause. If that's true, please rephrase the title (e.g. "Position of relative clause"). Apart, there's already a question here addressing that issue. Can't find it right now (I guess, it's poorly titled ;)). If, however, your question is about something else, you should update your question, because then it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Actually... Just realized that your [other question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11351/1224) asks for mainly the same thing. Those answers also fit to that question.

Comment: Yes it's similar (clause order) but I believe it is not the same like my previous question. Here I don't introduce a different subject. So I believe that the sentences are equally correct... or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "über" has to be part of the writing-clause because it is "schreiben über". Also, it would be most appropriate to use a da-word though some phrasings might be heard without it.

Best version:

> Ich habe ein paar Worte darüber geschrieben, was ich machen kann.

Ok version:

> Ich habe ein paar Worte darüber, was ich machen kann, geschrieben.

This is not very nice because having the da-word and an indefinite relative clause (was-relative clause) right after one another sounds odd

> Ich habe ein paar Worte über was ich machen kann geschrieben.

Occurs in spoken. Technically it's correct but DaF-teachers would mark it as false.